# Is there a field to get online meeting url if it is Microsoft Teams meeting?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When I use this API to get events

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2018-04-11T00:00:00.000Z&enddatetime=2018-04-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

If it is a Skype meeting, there will be a `onlineMeetingUrl` field and have the meeting url.

However, if it is a Microsoft Teams meeting, `onlineMeetingUrl` is null. Is there another special field for the meeting url? Thanks

Below is a Microsoft Teams meeting:

```
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"oCWUK/b/Ok2lJzxdSR2E9QABXMy2tg==\"",
        "id": "AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1hZjgyLTczYjAtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADgXLIICAAoo9AoyFmP0_4_YQHAKAllCv2-zpNpSc8XUkdhPUAAAIBDQAAAKAllCv2-zpNpSc8XUkdhPUAAVypLdQAAAA=",
        "createdDateTime": "2018-04-11T02:58:26.9190336Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-04-11T02:58:26.9971595Z",
        "changeKey": "oCWUK/b/Ok2lJzxdSR2E9QABXMy2tg==",
        "categories": [],
        "originalStartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
        "originalEndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
        "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F1F424ED40D1D301000000000000000010000000F51FB6A3836CAB4985F44D2D45E3AC0F",
        "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
        "isReminderOn": true,
        "hasAttachments": false,
        "subject": "Hi",
        "bodyPreview": "Hello",
        "importance": "normal",
        "sensitivity": "normal",
        "isAllDay": false,
        "isCancelled": false,
        "isOrganizer": false,
        "responseRequested": true,
        "seriesMasterId": null,
        "showAs": "tentative",
        "type": "singleInstance",
        "webLink": "https://outlook.live.com/owa/?itemid=AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1hZjgyLTczYjAtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADgXLIICAAoo9AoyFmP0%2B4%2BYQHAKAllCv2%2FzpNpSc8XUkdhPUAAAIBDQAAAKAllCv2%2FzpNpSc8XUkdhPUAAVypLdQAAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
        "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
        "responseStatus": {
            "response": "notResponded",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "Hello"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2018-04-12T03:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2018-04-12T03:30:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Here",
            "locationType": "default",
            "uniqueId": "Here",
            "uniqueIdType": "private"
        },
        "locations": [
            {
                "displayName": "Here",
                "locationType": "default",
                "uniqueId": "Here",
                "uniqueIdType": "private"
            }
        ],
        "recurrence": null,
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "none",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Jack",
                    "address": "Jack@example.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "none",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Rose",
                    "address": "Rose@example.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "organizer": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Jack",
                "address": "Jack@example.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working with the Microsoft Graph team on this, both to filter on online meetings, and to distinguish between Teams and Skype for Business meetings (as you have discovered, they use different properties).

I don't know the exact schedule, but you should see this in the beta endpoint of Microsoft Graph in the next few months.

**Update**: there is an undocumented way to get to it in the meantime, before it's officially exposed:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl')`