# Is there an extended property in Exchange for the VTC Conference ID of a Microsoft Teams Meeting?

Tags: exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams

I would like to get the VTC Conference ID for a Microsoft Teams Meeting from its corresponding appointment object in Exchange.

I found this answer for getting the URL for the meeting from a property  "SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl" in the public strings, but that unfortunately doesn't contain the VTC Conference ID: [Is there a field to get online meeting url if it is Microsoft Teams meeting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765868/is-there-a-field-to-get-online-meeting-url-if-it-is-microsoft-teams-meeting)

I've tried stabbing in the dark with by attempting to get "SkypeTeamsMeetingId" and "VTCConferenceId" from the public strings, but have not been successful.

Does anyone know if the VTC Conference ID is stored in an extended property in Exchange and how to access it?

Comment: Take a look at meeting yourself with a Mapi Editor like OutlookSpy or MFCMapi this will tell you exactly what Mapi properties are available on an Item and what property Guid combination you should use

Comment: Could you please take a look at [Get Online Meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)? Let us know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can always '**scrape**' the meting object (you need to monitor the calendar of the room/person) or get the invitation by any means and then read the content of the meeting invitation.

take a look at this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http